# Why do I keep getting a "type is not defined" in my VB.Net application at compile time?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a vb.Net application where I've incorporated a control that was custom developed by somebody else.  I've incorporated the control into my application but I periodically get the message "Type 'myMapControl.myMapControl' is not defined" when I compile.  The error is in the Form1.Designer.vb file on the following lines (my form name is "Form1" in this case.)

```
   Me.myMapControl1= New myMapControl.myMapControl
   Me.myOthermapControl = New myMapControl.myMapControl
```

If I add a "Global" qualifier:

```
   Me.myMapControl1= New Global.myMapControl.myMapControl
   Me.myOthermapControl = New Global.myMapControl.myMapControl
```

then I can compile and everything works fine for a while.  I can compile, change, re-compile, etc.  However eventually, the "Global" qualifier disappears and I have to re-add it.  What am I doing wrong.  I've made sure that the control's dll was added as a reference.

Comment: Is it possible you have a namespace collision? What is the namespace of your current project?

Comment: This is a common VS2010 trap.  Change the .NET framework target from the Client profile to the full profile.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem.  I'd been a bit dumb and named the control the same the default namespace for the project

**Namespace** = *PAStatusGrid* 
**Control** = *PAStatusGrid.vb*

Each time you edit the design of your form it regenerates the .designer.vb code and the removes the [Global.] prefix that you have to put in.

Check your control names and namespaces and make sure they don't conflict

Answer (score 0):

the designer.vb file is edited dynamically by form editor GUI. this is why the global command is disappearing. an idea to make it not need this is to set the compile property on the dll file make sure that it is compiled into the debug folder. hope this helps.